# Facebook Graph API: How can I retrieve the number of views of a video I shared from another profile using the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, facebook-php-sdk, analytics

I have a business manager account for my Facebook profile and I re-shared a video from another profile. How can I retrieve the number of views that my re-share accounted for through the Facebook Graph API?

If the video were posted directly to my profile rather than re-shared, I'd be able to use the [/v2.8/{video-id}/video_insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/video_insights) method to retrieve the video stats, but that does not appear to be available for re-shares. The only insights that I can find for re-shares appears to be [/v2.8/{post-id}/insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/post), but that does not include video views.

For example, here is a [Facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/thedodosite/posts/1051346635000011) by The Dodo where they are re-sharing a video by Discovery News.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information can be retrieved by making a call to [/v2.8/{post-id}/insights/post_video_views](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/insights)